# I have been trying to get my css to work with my html

Tags: html, css

I cant get css and html code to work together using padding,margin, floats. I'm stuck. If put float left it stays in the middle. Basically it won't size properly. I hope this explains it... I'm frustrated

I have tried my books, google, w3schools. I just seem to be missing something. I'm in a coding boot camp and I don't have time in class to ask everything I need to.

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Easier Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h6>header</h6>
        </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

MyCSS:

```
.container {
    padding: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gray;

}

#header{
   width: 600px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   float: right;
   background-color: white;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  What's the desired output look like?

Comment: Your CSS works fine (despite setting a wide fixed `width` and very high `padding` and `margin` -- which I would advise against). What exactly is the problem? That your CSS isn't loading? Is your CSS file called `style.css`, and is it in the same folder as the HTML file? If so, have you tried clearing your cache? Try `CTRL` + `ALT` + `R`.

Comment: it is uploaded to a repository.so they're all in the same folder. I need to make a wire frame website model in html and css. not sure if I'm using DIV's correctly. What I would really like is a basic website html and css template I can reference so I can check myself on the way I'm linking my css to my html as well as making sure I can set multiple boxes in a structured form using CSS. I have been looking for is a .PDF or something that shows a proper HTML and CSS sheets that are linked just showing the code. Like a smaller website that works, but just showing code. Any ideas where to get that

Comment: Please go read [ask]. The titles of the last couple of questions you asked here more are of the “chatty” variety, whereas actually they should give a short description of the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to give a particular width to the container div,then float prorperty will work.
Float property works correctly only when the parent has been given  a sepecific width.